# Problem reach Azure FunctionApp for 'The remote name could not be resolved' error

Tags: azure, dns, azure-functions

I have an Azure FunctionApp, it is working and is healthy, but sometimes I get an error 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net'' when try to call.

I'm using **Consumption plan** that has max timeout 10min, can this cause mentioned issue if the process take more time and reach timeout?

Or can **function app cold start** cause similar problems?

What else to check?

thanks for any hints

Comment: It might be due to the Firewall Setting which blocks the Connection or the DNS Server!

Comment: Hey HariKrishnaRajoli, thanks for reply, actually it is not failing every time, from time to time this error is thrown, so I believe system settings, permissions and the configuration is set correctly as this works by default.

Comment: Hello @JanTeplan, what would be the cause you identified any, is it working well these days?

Comment: Hey @HariKrishnaRajoli, unfortunatelly this is still a case, not critical as occur randomly from time to time, but will be great to know the reason for this. If I'll have any update for this, will post...

Comment: @JanTeplan Did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue with the web app service. Thanks

Comment: @Paresh, hi unfortunately no any update for this case, it occur randomly, if I have any update will post in here